# Is there a customizable Cocoa control for iOS that looks like the Date/Time picker in Readdle's Calendars iPad application?

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios7, cocoapods

I really like the way that there's a clean separation between hours and minutes.
Ideally on Cocoapods.
I actually want to use something similar for selecting weights and measures.

[image: Readdle date/time picker]

Comment: Please post a picture of the control you want to duplicate - hard to know what you want to do without one. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Heya, I've uploaded a picture. It's got also separation between hours and minutes, which is really nicely presented.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is already a control on the web for that.
I searched on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ which is a great reference for iOS & OSX custom controls made by users, and did not find anything like your pic.

But that would be really easy to do it yourself:

1. Use a first `UICollectionView` (with horizontal scrolling) to present cells displaying the hours ("20:00", "21:00", etc). You can use custom `UICollectionViewCells` to have a big label with the hours (for which you will provide an IBOutlet to change it for each cell) and a smaller label for the smaller ":00" part (without any outlet needed for this one)
2. Likewise, use a second `UICollectionView` for the minutes as well

Then you can build your time according to the selected cells in both collection views.
Or directly build an `NSDate` object using `NSDateComponents` to provide the hours and minutes components of your date separately, then building the date from the individual components.

Comment: Hmm. Very good idea — I didn't think of using `UICollectionView`. I was hoping to use something off the shelf. Thanks!